# iOS Firebase Cloud Messaging not working until user toggles notifications in Settings app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, unusernotificationcenter

I'm having the following issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) on iOS:

1) On first app launch, user accepts notifications (alerts, badges, sounds).

2) User proceeds to use the app and does not receive any Firebase notifications. I have another client receiving the notifications so I can verify that they are being sent.

3) User goes to iOS Settings app, toggles notifications off then back on for my app, and then returns to the app.

4) Users properly receives all following Firebase notifications.

I am only using Firebase Messaging for silent notifications (i.e. "content_available": true) and I'm requesting user notifications with the following swift code:

```
// Setup APN
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
    callback(granted)
}
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

// Setup Firebase Messaging
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

---

**Example Message**

All of my Firebase Messages are of the form:

```
[
    "type": <string>,    // Message name 
    "aps": {
        "content-available" = 1;
    }, 
    "gcm.message_id": <int>, 
    "payload": {
        "id": <string>,    
         ...             // Other JSON fields
    }
]
```

Comment: can you please share the content in the notification form the server.

Comment: Appended an example Firebase Message to my original post.